# How to select the matching records when the where clause contains an array column?

Tags: arrays, postgresql

In a project I have a table called `documents` from where I have to select all the records as `documents.id` where I have a `documents.recipients`.

The resulting record I need to have is:

| documentId | recipentId |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | gmiG_duuBQOX6WblPXpUk |
| 1 | TQ7o1lBsrfDPtBeqGnyYt |
| 2 | gmiG_duuBQOX6WblPXpUk |
| 2 | TQ7o1lBsrfDPtBeqGnyYt |

The problem is as you see from table screenshot that the recipients are an array and I have no idea how to make this matching.

[image: Table example]

The document can have many recipients, not only 2 as showed in this dummy table, and I have to match all the documents to one recipient ID.

E.G. `[{r1,d1},{r1,d2},{r2,d3}]`

The result I need to be able to construct a payload in an API later where I have to send an OBJ as e.g.

```json
{
  "phone": null,
  "email": "foo@bar.com",
  "recipients": [{r1,d1},{r1,d2},{r2,d3}]
}
```

However, the above OBJ was added only for a competition of information.
The help I need is to construct a PostgreSQL query which can result on what I described before and resolving that issue I have with the recipients be an array.

I've been trying as follow but not really understood how to do it:

```sql
select
    id,
    recipients
from
    documents d
where
    recipients -> '0' = 'gmiG_duuBQOX6WblPXpUk'
```

As edit added the screenshot of properties of this table

[image: properties]

Comment: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/arrays.html & https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-array.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `jsonb` containment operator `@>` to find all lines where the recipient contains a certain recipient:

```
SELECT d.id, 'gmiG_duuBQOX6WblPXpUk'
FROM documents d
WHERE d.recipients @> ARRAY['gmiG_duuBQOX6WblPXpUk'];
```

Comment: Ok, I have spelled it out in my updated answer.

Comment: I tried and no results. What I did was like this which gave me a result
SELECT *
FROM(
SELECT d.id id, unnest(d.recipients) recipient
FROM documents d) as result
WHERE recipient=&#39;aaaa&#39;

Comment: That means that there is no such recipient.

Comment: Not really I used that Id and I found many documents attached to that ID I solved with using the other method I shared by the way